# Use jQuery to select sibling elements matching class adjacent to clicked element

Tags: jquery

Given this list of elements:

```
<ul id="menu3">
    <li>DELI MEATS</li>
    <li class="subhead">Ham</li>
    <li class="sub">Cooked Ham</li>
    <li class="sub">Pepper Ham</li>
    <li class="sub">Tavern Ham</li>
    <li class="sub">Italian Brand Ham</li>
    <li class="subhead">Roast Beef</li>
    <li class="sub">Roast Beef</li>
    <li class="sub">Italian Style Roast Beef</li>
    <li>Turkey</li>
    <li>Italian</li>
    <li class="subhead">Bologna</li>
    <li class="sub">Deli Bologna</li>
    <li class="sub">Garlic Bologna</li>
    <li>Liverwurst</li>
    <li>Pepperoni</li>
    <li>Pastrami</li>
    <li>Corned Beef</li>
</ul>
```

When the second LI element is clicked ("Ham"), I want to select with jQuery the LI elements after the clicked element with class="sub", but only going down to (and including) Italian Brand Ham. I.e., I want it to stop (and not include) Roast Beef, because it does not have class="sub".

```
$('#menu3 li').on('click', function(){
// Get LI element with class="sub" directly following the clicked element.
});
```

Is this possible? Thank you!

Comment: but if you click on `DELI MEATS` or `Deli Bologna` what should happen

Comment: Sounds like you should use nested lists, or a definition list, instead. But in the meantime: http://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/

Comment: Should all the list items be bound on click, or just the subhead class ones?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for `nextUntil()`:

http://jsfiddle.net/NXwB5/

```
$(this).nextUntil('.subhead');
```

Or maybe (to only select `.sub` elements:

```
$(this).nextUntil('.subhead', '.sub')
```

Though there are some edge cases you haven't defined that will probably change the exact answer.